# Create Shopify Product with Image & Price using API PHP

Tags: php, shopify

I have this code and it creates a product but no price and image. I tried to replace each on array with default value but still it does not add image and price. What is wrong with this code/array? Thanks!

```
    $products_array = array(
    "product"=>array(
        "title"=> "title",
        "body_html"=> "description",
        "vendor"=> "vendor",
        "product_type"=> "type",
        "published"=> false ,
        "variants" => array
        (
            array
            (
                "price" => 15.00,
            )
        ),
        "images" => array(
            array(
                "src" => "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/PIC2-3.jpg",
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[according to doc](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product) It should be array of object

```
 "variants" => [
        {
            "price" => 15.00,
        }
    ],
"images": [
  {
    "src": "http://example.com/rails_logo.gif"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is what OP is doing. He post PHP array while you post a JSON

Comment: Yaa so excelty the problem is array and api require jsaon inside array you can verify in doc

Comment: If you apply `json_encode` to the `$products_array` they showed, then you _will_ get `"images":[{"src":"…"}]` in that place automatically – since “associative arrays” do not exist in JSON, this is _automatically_ converted to object syntax.